# Mysql Time Epoch restar 4 horas

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

¿Cómo le resto 4 horas a un campo que esta en formato Time Epoch `1475638722`?

Intenté con `DATE_SUB(field,INTERVAL 4 HOUR)` pero no lo conseguí.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer uso de [from-unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) para luego aplicar el `DATE_SUB()`

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(field),INTERVAL 4 HOUR )  from  nameTable;
```

[demostración](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ed049/5/0)

Respuesta al Comentario

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(field),INTERVAL 4 HOUR ))  from mytable
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta si hace la funcion pero me lo regresa en formato aaaa-mm-dd HH:MM:SS, se puede que me lo regrese igual en formato Time Epoch, 
por ejemplo asi 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD((NOW()),INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
a la hora actual le sumo 1 hora y me lo regresa en formato Time Epoch,

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta. espero ayude.